# Transform date while loop into for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I have following while loop in Python:

```
start_date: datetime.date = utcnow().date() - datetime.timedelta(
    days=30
)
end_date: datetime.date = utcnow().date()
DELTA_1D: datetime.timedelta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
while start_date <= end_date:
    # some code
    start_date += DELTA_1D
```

But I want to transform it to a `for loop`. What's the best implementation for this?

Answer (score 1):

Work out he number of days between by simply subtracting

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

d0 = date(2008, 8, 18)
d1 = date(2008, 9, 26)
delta = d1 - d0
for i in range(0,delta.days):
        date_to_handle = d0 + timedelta(days=i)
```

Comment: I want to know which date I handle so this is a bit to complex than

Comment: Do you want a `for each` loop?

Comment: I want to loop over each day between those 2 intervals and know which date I'm handling

Comment: Updated so that imports are included and you have the date within the for loop

Comment: You can do this with date or datetiem @sg_sg94